# Secretive and confusing work environment?

Tags: communication, work-environment, feedback, secrecy

Two months ago I landed a job in a company, my role is shared with an employee who was appointed a month before me. From the moment I got through the door I noticed that the other employees where being very wary and somewhat reluctant of answering work-related questions. Management set a training program but my direct manager made it clear through various interactions he would rather keep communication to a minimum.

Additionally I am not being included in email CCs and I am not given any tasks that are clear. All what I've learned about the job was through lurking around other peoples offices. The cherry on top was last week when a fellow employee was told that both me and him are showing no involvement in work related activities and are wasting time.

Could this be a sign I am about to be let go soon? What can I do to communicate more with my direct manager - and if it is true that I am about to be let go, is there a way to salvage this?

Comment: So you were hired for a role, were given no information on what your actual job is, were given no tasks or responsibilities, and then were told your job performance is poor? That's pretty strange.

Answer (score 1):

Focus on the facts. Your review says you are making no improvement.  Your job is in jeopardy.

First, most people are given more than two or three months to learn a job.

You need to discuss the review with your boss. This is not the time to blame your coworkers and environment.

Ask what you need to do to show improvement.  You can ask to schedule regular meetings with your boss. Offer to check in via email regularly.  Let your boss know what you need from him to help do your job.  Do you need your job responsibilities clarified?  Do not tell your boss you find your coworkers unfriendly and the company culture stifling.  Your boss can not help with that.

It would also be helpful to build relationships that you need to get your job done.  You may need to adjust your presentation to connect.  How do you dress/ communicate?  Do you show interest in your coworkers and ther lives?  Schedule meetings and ask people about their jobs and how it relates to you.

If this position and company are not for you, get out as soon as you can.

Comment: i am not assigning blame it just feels like i was hired as a back up in case the other guy does not cut it , i feel like they are confident he can handle his own and i am no longer needed. also checking the companies history i noticed that the employee turnover is fairly high

Comment: Do not concede the job to the other guy. Take your share of assignments if you can.

Comment: I think you should work on two fronts. Try to make this job work. Plus start looking for other positions.  I am concerned your dissatisfaction is not unique to this organization.  The grass is not always greener on the other side of the fence.